# Anyone using Asus K55VM-SX086D Laptop for running ROS

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community

I saw few threads regarding laptop recommendation, please forgive me for adding one more.

I am planning to buy Asus K55VM-SX086D Laptop (http://www.flipkart.com/asus-k55vm-sx086d-laptop-3rd-gen-ci7-8gb-1tb-dos-2gb-graph/p/itmd7vs3cgw4twkr)

I am going for a laptop coz I will be moving a lot (so desktop is not an option). Mostly I will be doing my work on a simulated home environment with PR2 robot.

Running object manipulation stack (and also navigation).

Kindly let me know:-

1. If someone is using this or similar config (i7 3610QM, 2.3 GHz with Turbo Boost Upto 3.3 GHz, 6MB Cache, NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M 2GB, 8GB RAM), how much simulation speed can I expect when I will be running:-

   - PR2 in simulated home (say 10 table chair and 20 household graspable object)
   - While object manipulation stack will be called.
   - With navigation stack.
2. I would like to have a speed of at least 0.15x when running those stacks. With my experience on i3 desktop I guess I should get this much on this machine. However if not then any better laptop suggestion. My budget can go up to twice as much as this.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72910/anyone-using-asus-k55vm-sx086d-laptop-for-running-ros/) by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2013-08-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there Aknirala!
I've got an [Asus ROG](http://a.co/2QdO2xW) that was around 900$ at the time if I remember correctly, it has twice the ram than the K55VM, it has an i7-4720HQ 2.6 GHz Processor and for the graphics card, it has a Geforce 960M.
I've never had a problem with it, quite the opposite I was able to run very complex simulations (with the Atlas and Valkyrie Robot), pointclouds, rviz, some deep learning nodes and while the fan was ultra loud it never gave up on me.

If you are getting a laptop, I recommended getting something that is oriented towards gamers, since you'd likely require most of the things they do.

Also, whatever you are getting, please make sure to get an SSD. My laptop came with 1TB HDD but after changing to a Samsung EVO SSD I notices around 20% improvement.

Also, ram is important apart from video, so that 8GB ram will be eaten up really quick, 16GB or 32Gb would be the ideal number, then again, it depends on your budget!

P.S. I used Caffe and Digits for deep learning and I could train my models in my laptop, it was slow compared to a desktop but it worked, so I'd leave the laptop training overnight and I was done.

P.P.S. And I play games on it on a dual boot so I am all set :D

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0